# Adding a number in increments of 1000 to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that has an ID column.  I need the column to be in increments of 1000.  so it would be 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, etc until the end of the recordset.  Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There si more possible solutions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

df['ID'] = range(1000, (len(df.index)+1) * 1000, 1000)
print (df)
   A  F    ID
0  a  a  1000
1  b  a  2000
2  c  a  3000
3  d  b  4000
4  e  b  5000
5  f  b  6000
```